# Python: Remove soft hyphen(s)

Tags: python, html

in a html file, I've got words containing soft hyphens, e.g

```
"Schilde rung"
repr(word) = "Schilde\\xc2\\xadrung"
```

How can I remove them?

Since my file also contains umlaute and other special chars, solutions with printable or with `words.decode('ascii', 'ignore')` aren't terribly good...

I already tried it using `words.replace('\xc2\xad', '')`; but this didn't work.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I'm missing the code. What is `words`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't run `replace` on a list; you need to run it on each member of the list:

```
words = ["Hello", "Schilde\xc2\xadrung"]
words = [word.replace('\xc2\xad', '') for word in words]
print repr(words)
# Prints ['Hello', 'Schilderung']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. With this solution, everything works fine :) I didn't see the mistake.